# Yii - CGridView 1-to-N Display issues

Tags: yii, cgridview

I've started Yii a month ago and am finding it very intuitive, yet somehow confusing regarding widgets.

In the app i'm developing, **although I sometimes use Active Record, I cannot use it's relations as I am using MyIsam** (and this cannot be changed) and it has no support for foreign keys.

My issue is I have a *CGridView* and want to add custom data to it, but am having issues.

It is a *1-to-many* relationship with the *FK* in the right model, but as I said, I cannot use *AR's* magic.

I have this, an Applications Model and a Profile model. The Profile model has an application *FK*.

I got a function so when I'm rendering the CGrid I can fetch the name of each Application instead of its *id_app*.

```
public function appName($id){
    $app= Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
        ->select('name')
        ->from('tbl_aplications a')
        ->where('a.id=:id_app', array(':id_app'=>$id))
        ->queryRow();

    return $app;
}
```

In the auto-generated templates, in the Profile Admin.php view, I got:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'profile-application-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(), //maybe the issue is with this criteria? It is currently 'as-is' after the template generation
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        'id',
        'name',
                array(
                    'name'=>'id_app',
                    'header'=>'Aplication',
```

And here is my issue, I've tried (and all sorts of variations):

```
'value' => 'ProfileApplication::model()->appName($data->id_app)',
'value' => 'ProfileApplication::model()->appName(id_app)',
'value' => 'ProfileApplication::model()->appName("id_app")',
```

and all I get is *null* as a result because it is passing the actual string instead of each row's value. If I pass a direct ID to the function's query, it returns correct value, like `->where('a.id=:id_app', array(':id_app'=>3))`

Is it the search criteria that needs to be altered?
I've found similar questions but all of them use AR such as *Profile->application* or something along those lines and I as I said, I cannot use it due to *MyIsam* restrictions.

Any tips are appreciated to this newcomer, or links to a solution regarding a similar issue .

Comment: The only thing with MyISAM is that it won't auto-detect the relations for you when you generate the model. You can put the relations in yourself however, and you will have all the magic you want.  See my answer below for how to use the value attribute to access properties of related models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the value attribute such as that you need, as PrplHaz4 said, a data provider.  Then, the $data variable is what has the magic, and it must be used in a string because it is eval()'ed behind the scenes.  Here is an example of what you are trying to do:

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'item-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'columns'=>array(
        array(
            'name' => 'id',
            'header' => 'Item ID',

        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'category_search',
            'header' => 'Category',
            'value' => '$data->category->name',
        ),
    ),
)); ?>
```

That grabs the name attribute of the related item category model.  In the relations() function of the item model:

```
return array(
    'category'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'ItemCategory', 'category_id'),
);
```

And in the relations() function of the item category model:

```
return array(
    'items'=>array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Item', 'category_id'),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should still be able to use ActiveRecord relations with MyISAM, I beleive the only difference is that with MyISAM, if you use a model generator (gii or cmd line), it will not automatically create the relations.  Instead, you will have to specify the relation yourself in the Profile model.  This is effectively creating a "soft" fk for use with AR.

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'applications'=>array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Applications', 'id_app'),
    );
}
```

That will not entirely solve your problem though, because you will need to use a dataprovider that brings the application models along with the profile models.  Something like this:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
  'id'=>'profile-application-grid',
  'dataProvider'=>Profile::model()->with('Applications'),
  'filter'=>$model,
  'columns'=>array(
    'id',
    'name',
    array(
      'name'=>'applications.name',
      'header'=>'Application',
    ),
```

Comment: Hum...I'm getting `ProfileApplication and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "getData" `.